# Try until no exception?

Tags: python, exception

```
def foo():
    try:
        html = get(url)
        while (html is nogood):
            foo()
        return html
    except Exception as e:
        changeip()
        foo()
```

The function `foo` simply returns a good html in text.
However, the function sometimes returns `None` and it's caused
when an `Exception` is caught.

So I changed the last line to `return foo()` and it works as expected.

The question is why? On catch, it simply calls foo again, which would eventually return a good html in text, why do I have to put the extra `return`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a recursion solution at all. In `foo`, just keep looping until you have a good html. After each time through the loop, do something to improve the chance to get a good html (does `changeip` work for this purpose?).

```
def foo():
    while True:
        try:
            html = get(url)
            if is_good(html):
                return html
        except Exception:  # Need specific exception, do not catch all
            changeip()
```

Comment: changeip does work , its uses Tor. Thanks for the improvement on the code

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the first `foo()` returns if it fails.

Call `foo1` from `main` and it fails -> `foo1` calls `foo2` and it succeeds -> `foo2` returns html to `foo1` -> there is no other code to execute in `foo1` so it returns `None`.

When `foo` finally succeeds, it doesn't return `html` to `main`, it returns it to the last caller, which in this case is `foo1`.

The problem is that you are discarding the results of any `foo` call after the first one fails. You need to return html back down the chain by the last line to `return foo()` as you mentioned.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not. Are you sure that line is ever run? If `html = get(url)` succeeds, that while loop doesn't get run, and if it fails the exception get called right?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a big cardboard box in the middle of a room. This box represents your function, `foo`. Now imagine that instead of `return` meaning what it does, we have it mean something like `change_this_boxes_colour`. Whatever colour the box changes to (the return value, really) can be seen from the room you're in currently. This is how the function gives you information.

Now, inside this big cardboard box is a little magical, because the box can create its own little boxes (including copies of itself!). So let's look at some code, and then think about it in box terms:

```
def bar():
    return BLUE  # every `bar` box turns `BLUE`

def foo():
    bar()

print(foo())  # prints None
```

Simple code right? This is a super-distilled version of your code. We're calling a function inside another function, but not getting its return value (colour).

Thinking in terms of boxes again, we have our big (colourless) box in the middle of the room. But it's made its own box (`bar`) inside itself. This box turns `BLUE`, as expected. But `foo` has no colour set (return value), so it remains colourless.

We're still standing outside the big `foo` box though, so we can't see what colour the `bar` box is. If we wanted to know what colour `bar` turned, `foo` would have to tell us. This can be achieved by asking `foo` to set itself to the same colour as it sees `bar` go. In this case, `"BLUE"`.

```
def bar():
    return "BLUE"  # every `bar` box turns "BLUE"

def foo():
    return bar()  # change our colour to the same colour as `bar`

print(foo())  # prints "BLUE"
```

In your case, `foo` happens to create versions of itself inside its own box, but the principle still applies.

Comment: This will hopefully explain your original question, but @hai-vu is correct that recursion is not only unnecessary, but arguably an error (since Python has a recursion limit).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It's clear now.